# DNS responses received by server 2008 but nothing is resolving - Site to Site VPN

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

So, I have a Site to Site VPN from my Main office (192.168.0.x - Cincinnati) to my branch office (192.168.1.x - Chicago).

I was having some issues that prompted me to add domain controller at Chicago to remedy my problems. (DNS speed, and occasional logon issues)

The problem I am having is the server in Chicago (192.168.1.2) is receiving DNS responses from the Cincinnati server (192.168.0.8) but it is either denying/dropping them and I have no clue what is going on.

Below are links to screen shots of packet captures. The one screenshot is from Wireshark and it shows that the server is receiving the DNS responses. The other screenshot is from Microsoft Network Monitor (3.4) and it is showing that it is sending DNS queries, but not receiving any responses.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/btaJa.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjYm5.jpg

I appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: What is doing the VPN connectivity between Cincinnati and Chicago?  Could an edge device (firewall) be preventing the inbound VPN replies?  DNS is a UDP-based protocol, so a stateful firewall is required to open a pinhole for the reverse traffic.

Comment: The VPN is an IPsec VPN between a cisco concentrator and a sonicwall tz210. I know the only proof I posted is a pcap, but I am 90% sure that the traffic is getting to the server... but the server is not accepting it. 

I have been on a Microsoft forum if this helps you think of anything...

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverNIS/thread/ae5d7c2a-e475-4b15-9695-73aa3125247a

Comment: Can you set up syslogging on the Cisco/Sonicwall devices (and any edge firewalls in the network stack) and point them at a common syslog receiver?  This should give you a straightforward logical trail to determine whether connections are being dropped by any intermediary device.  Otherwise, you are going to have to pcap each device interface and analyse those to determine where the packets are dropped.

Comment: I have done both of those exactly with the exact same result... they are passing through everything and stop at the server in Chicago. I just made a little progress... it is for sure something with the MS server. The link I posted last comment is slowing taking me a few directions

Comment: What filter did you use on your Wireshark screenshots?  Was it an `ip.addr`-based filter or a `udp.port`-based filter?

Comment: I used ip.addr. 

I got the original problem solved... but it still looks like there is some connectivity problems which I just don't understand. 

I noticed in logs that the server is not getting GPO updates and is not getting NTP from the domain server... so there is obviously some sort of connectivity/time out going on here but I have no clue how to go about finding that.

Comment: Try with a `udp.port`-based filter, instead: it might help to factor out any NAT/inspect-related problems (e.g. if the server replies are NAT'ed to a different address before reaching the client, the client might drop/ignore them because it is expecting replies from the pre-NAT address).  Of course, it won't help if you're also having PAT issues...